# Booting ubuntu usb gives terminal?? How can I install ubuntu?

Tags: system-installation

I have NOT installed ubuntu, and I want to; the guidelines on the website suggest that when I boot from the USB I get some kind of a GUI which guides me through setup; however, what I get is a black terminal screen. What is going wrong here?

I have ubuntu-14.10-desktop-amd64.iso on my formatted USB.

Comment: what video card do you have? is the md5sum ok on the iso?

Comment: Looks like you have desktop version, not server, which was my first guess. Could you have accidentally downloaded wrong iso ? Does clicking Ctrl+Alt+F7 give you the gui or not ?

Answer (score 0):

The process of putting an iso on a usb drive is a bit more complicated than just putting the iso on the drive. I recommend you used the [universal usb installer](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/) if you're installing from windows. It should work nicely with the iso file you already have so be sure you have that on your hard drive before you format the usb drive.

Other good methods are listed [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows).

Comment: If the OP had just copied the .iso file to the USB flash drive, it would never have even started to boot from it all. This would only produce something describable as "a black terminal screen" if the installed OS were broken and unbootable (or perhaps if no OS were installed already). So while the wording of the question does make it sound a little bit like the OP just put the .iso file on the USB flash drive by copying it, I suspect they really did write (or attempt to write) it to the USB stick with one of the widely recommended methods.